# Do we need support for kanji tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, kanji

Currently it seems the stackexchange engine only supports english characters in tags - if you, for example, put 一人称 in the tags field it will be ignored. Do we need/want support for such tags?

Comment: As an update: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135929/add-non-latin-character-set-support-for-tags

Answer (score 6):

I like the idea of supporting new users whom may not read kanji - why not use romaji?  On the tag wiki page, the proper kanji may be used, should anyone want to know what that tag "really means".

Answer (score 4):

For info, non-ascii tags have now been enabled on both JLU and meta.JLU. A slight caveat: this code is new, so if there are any issues please let me know directly (a comment here would be fine, just as long as I see it).

If the site community feels this is not helpful, we can turn it back off, but for now: enjoy, but please consider (perhaps a discussion here on meta.JLU is in order) the *most appropriate*  use of such tags.

The tag edit on this question is entirely gratuitous and unnecessary; please feel free to edit it back out...