# Adding alternative tags for particles

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

I am only a semi-frequent visitor, but I really enjoy the site.  It's kind of a pain to fumble around with the tags.  I think it would be VERY easy to add some tag alternatives and save all users, new and old, a ton of hassle to add these alternatives for all the particles:

(currently "particle-wo"), wo, wo-particle.

I'm sorry, but the first thing that comes to my mind is "を" when I'm writing content that features that particle.  The second thing is "を-particle".  The third thing, which comes up as a suggestion when I type the earlier two, anyway, is "particle-wo".

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: I messed this up and added 'wo' as a particle.  My rep is 20 points off, so I had to go through human verification.  Oh, man!  Let me just get back to my life! lol

Answer (score 2):

When the tags were all originally being created, [you couldn't have non-English characters in the tag names](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/do-we-need-support-for-kanji-tags).  From some quick testing on your question, it appears this is still the case.

I agree it would be helpful to at least have higarana in the particle tags, but it's really a technical limitation that there aren't tags like "を-particle".