# Kanji tags - now available!

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Marc Gravell [announced the new support for Kanji tags](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/966/1063) a couple weeks back, but it looks like it may have gone unnoticed.

You are one of the first site that's getting this feature, so there may be some bugs lurking around. If you run into any issues either with the Kanji tags or with the plain old English tags, please let us know right away. You can post any issues you find in this thread.

Other language sites tend to use their native language tags as primary and set up synonyms in English, but you could go either way - up to and including not using non-English tags at all.

Still, we'd love some feedback on how these are working or whether you've chosen not to use them.

Thanks and enjoy!

Comment: May be this is the first step to UI translation of JLU site.

Comment: Just so you don't miss it: there's been some (at the time of this comment, ongoing) conversation about this at http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/971

Comment: "Kanji tags - now available!" just appeared in the "Featured on Meta" page. Which is a bit confusing in 2015...

Answer (score 3):

It appears that "kanji tags" don't work quite the same as usual tags. In particular, we have a couple of [tag synonyms](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms), e.g.
[助動詞](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%e5%8a%a9%e5%8b%95%e8%a9%9e) is a synonym of [auxiliaries](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auxiliaries), but it doesn't appear live like other tags:

[image: no live tag preview]

This is what should happen:

[image: live tag preview]

If someone types in a kanji tag, it would be nice for that person to see that this tag has already been created.

**Edit.** This appears to be a minor glitch (in Firefox?): The preview (correctly recognizing kanji tag synonyms) appears if I press backspace to delete one of the characters. It also appears if I copy/paste the tag name. But it *doesn't* find it if I type in a word with my IME and then convert it to kanji (that's how I guess anyone would enter a tag). The same seems to be the case on Japanese Stack Overflow.

Comment: I *think* it's working for me -- I tested with 助動詞 and it worked (in Chrome), but [tag:auxiliaries] now also has the Japanese translation in the tag excerpt in addition to the tag synonym, so it's not the same exact test. From your edit, my guess is that your browser isn't firing the relevant event (onkeydown? oninput?) on kanji-completion for some reason.

Comment: I'm using Firefox on ubuntu, which (I think) is a pretty popular browser-OS combination. It's working for me in Chromium (and I'm guessing it'd work in Chrome). Could someone check whether it's working in Firefox on other platforms?

Comment: Works in Firefox 39 (32-bit) on Windows 8.1, with a caveat that while results do show, I need to trigger another key press (even a simple arrow key suffices) to get relevant results.

Chrome 44.0.2403.89 (64-bit) works as expected with no extra key presses.